# Adding more than 5000 paths string in ElevationProfile using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I'm creating a simple [ElevationProfile](https://elevation.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tools/ElevationSync/GPServer) using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

In the URL it's described as

```
MaximumRecords: 5000
```

Its allows only 5000 polyline array paths but I have more than 5000 polyline array paths (ex : 12,000).

Is it possible to send the more than 5000 polyline path? If not, can I Compress the large polyline array into below 5000?

Give suggestion for the above and how to proceed?

Comment: Do you have the option to generalize the polyline or do you have to keep the current data density?

Comment: @GavinR, I want to keep current data density...